# How to remove rows from a datatable after grouping variables?

Tags: r

I have one data x with `id`, `date`, and `details` columns:

```
id date                 details
1  28-07-2017 20:01:30  NA
2  28-07-2017 18:01:30  NA
1  28-07-2017 22:02:20  SQL
2  28-07-2017 19:01:30  SQL
1  29-07-2017 22:20:00  NA
3  30-07-2017 18:01:30  NA
3  31-07-2017 18:01:30  SQL
4  28-07-2017 18:01:30  NA
```

I want my data look like this:

```
id date                 details
1  28-07-2017 20:01:30  NA
1  28-07-2017 22:02:20  SQL
2  28-07-2017 18:01:30  NA
2  28-07-2017 19:01:30  SQL
3  30-07-2017 18:01:30  NA
3  31-07-2017 18:01:30  SQL
4  28-07-2017 18:01:30  NA
```

I want to group data x on the basis of `id`, then sort `date` in ascending order, then if there is a "SQL" value in the `details` column then delete the below rows of same `id`. There should be no records on each `id` once SQL stage arrives in `details` variable.

How can I do this in R?

Comment: Could you add a [reproducible example of the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Use `dput` to convert your data into something that we can work with. Here's a link to understand it: https://gist.github.com/dsparks/3688652

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16888328)

Comment: The data was in an unusable form when I commented. The asker updated the question (making the data easier to understand), making my initial comment irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `dplyr` package along with `magrittr`. Here's a quick stab at it.

```
library("dplyr")
library("magrittr")
newdata <- olddata %>% group_by(id) %>% arrange (date) %>% filter(details !="SQL")
```